# Creating several windows around a date

Tags: sas, time-series

I am working with a dataset which has several stocks and I merged a data set with events onto it (for the stocks, several events in the period per stock).

Now, for an event study, I want to create several variables that act as dummies and create windows: -60 to -11 days, -5 to -1 day and announcement day plus day +1. 
Important are two things:

1. It has to be by Stock (the windows should not be carried over between stocks)
2. one announcement/event day (ann_day) should not spoil another event's window.

I tried the following but it is just giving me a window and does not account for different stocks and spoiled windows:

```
proc sql; 
   create view event_study as 
   select distinct b.ann_date,a.date,a.dayid-b.dayid as event_time, a.stock,a.return
   from Dataset_full as a,Announcements as b 
   where a.dayid-b.dayid between -60 and 11 and a.secid=b.secid
   order by a.stockb.ann_date,event_time; 
quit;
```

Some info: announcement days are the events
dataset_full has the stock, date, return, volume.  One row per calendar/trading day.
Announcement has stock, announcement date and announcement info (one row per announcement)
Data should look like this:

```
Stock   Date    Ann_date    flag_minus60_minus11    flag_minus5_minus1  flag_day0_day1
A   1/01/2016           1   
A   2/01/2016           1   
A   3/01/2016               
A   4/01/2016   4/01/2016           1
A   5/01/2016               1
A   6/01/2016               
A   7/01/2016               
A   8/01/2016               
A   9/01/2016               
A   10/01/2016              
A   11/01/2016              
A   12/01/2016              
A   13/01/2016              
A   14/01/2016              
A   15/01/2016              
B   1/01/2016       1       
B   2/01/2016       1       
B   3/01/2016       1       
B   4/01/2016       1       
B   5/01/2016       1       
B   6/01/2016       1       
B   7/01/2016               
B   8/01/2016               
B   9/01/2016               
B   10/01/2016              
B   11/01/2016          1   
B   12/01/2016          1   
B   13/01/2016          1   
B   14/01/2016          1   
B   15/01/2016          1   
B   16/01/2016  16/01/2016          1
B   17/01/2016              1
B   18/01/2016          1   
B   19/01/2016          1   
B   20/01/2016  20/01/2016          1
B   21/01/2016              1
B   22/01/2016              
B   23/01/2016              
B   24/01/2016              
B   25/01/2016
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MaBo:

Here is some sample data and SQL.  When you examine the output, I presume you will see 'spoiled' information -- that being a date with more than one future announcement in the flagging time frame.

The issue of flagging trading dates with respect to an event date is inner join.  The inner join has to be performed for each flag being computed, and that inner join needs to be left joined to the trading data to get your 'want'.

```
data trading;
  do group = 1 to 4;
    do date = today()-1000 to today(); format date yymmdd10.;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

data announcement;
  do group = 1 to 4;
    do date = today()-1000 to today(); format date yymmdd10.;
      if ranuni(123) < 0.01 then output;
    end;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  create table trading_pre_announce_flagged as
  select 
    trading.*
  , announcement.date as annouce_date
  , case when P0.date is not null then 1 else . end as P0_flag label="Announcement was today or yesterday"
  , case when P1.date is not null then 1 else . end as P1_flag label="Announcement in 1 to 5 days"
  , case when P2.date is not null then 1 else . end as P2_flag label="Announcement in 11 to 60 days"
  , case when P2.date is not null then P2.adate else . end as P2_date label="Date of Announcement in 11 to 60 days" format=yymmdd10.

  from
    trading
  left join 
    announcement 
    on announcement.date = trading.date and announcement.group = trading.group
  left join 
    ( select trading.group, trading.date 
      from trading 
      inner join 
      announcement 
      on    announcement.group = trading.group 
        and announcement.date - trading.date between -1 and 0
    ) as P0
    on P0.date = trading.date and P0.group = trading.group
  left join 
    ( select trading.group, trading.date 
      from trading 
      inner join 
      announcement 
      on    announcement.group = trading.group 
        and announcement.date - trading.date between 1 and 5
    ) as P1
    on P1.date = trading.date and P1.group = trading.group
  left join 
    ( select trading.group, trading.date, announcement.date as adate
      from trading 
      inner join 
      announcement 
      on    announcement.group = trading.group 
      where announcement.date - trading.date between 11 and 60
    ) as P2
    on P2.date = trading.date and P2.group = trading.group
  order
    by trading.group, trading.date
  ;
quit;
```

At some point (can't find it though) the OP mentioned processing ~750 companies and 500 overall events, and that the SQL solution seemed to be long running.

An alternative would be DATA Step.

The 500 events is a small enough cardinality where arrays of group and date could be used to store the events for lookup. Smart index tracking of the sorted events can be used for doing a minimum scan for evaluating the rules and applying the condition flags.

For example:

```
data trading;
  do group = 1 to 700;
    do date = today()-1000 to today(); format date yymmdd10.;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

data announcement;
  do eventid = 1 to 500;
    group = ceil(700*ranuni(123));
    date = (today()-1000) + ceil(1000*ranuni(123)); format date yymmdd10.;
    if mod(eventid,20) = 1 then do;
      output;
      eventid+1;
      date = date + 30 + floor(100*ranuni(123));
      output;
      eventid+1;
      date = date + 30 + floor(100*ranuni(123));
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=announcement;
  by group date;
run;

data _null_;
  if 0 then set announcement nobs=nobs;
  call symputx ('top', nobs+1);
run;

data marked_trading;
  array e_group(0:&TOP) _temporary_;
  array e_date (0:&TOP) _temporary_;

  * load event array;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last_announcement);
    set announcement end=last_announcement;
    e_group(_n_) = group;
    e_date(_n_) = date;

    eix0 = 1;
    eix1 = 1;
  end;

  e_group(0) = 0; * sentinel;
  e_group(_n_) = 1e9; *sentinel;

  * evaluate flagging criteria for each trade group date;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last_trading);
    set trading end=last_trading;
    by group;
    if first.group then do;
      * discover indices of events associated with the group;
      do eix0 = eix0 by 1 while (e_group(eix0) < group); end;
      do eix1 = eix0 by 1 while (e_group(eix1) = group); end; eix1 = eix1 - 1;
      eix_group = e_group(eix0);
    end;

    p3_flag = .; p2_flag = .; p1_flag = .;
    if group = eix_group then do;
      * NOTE: bounds are evaluated only at loop initialization;
      * evaluate events for flagging a trade;
      do ix = eix0 to eix1;
        days_to_event = e_date(ix) - date;

        if not p3_flag then if 11 <= days_to_event <= 60 then p3_flag = 1;
        if not p2_flag then if  1 <= days_to_event <= 5  then p2_flag = 1;
        if not p1_flag then if -1 <= days_to_event <= 0  then p1_flag = 1;

        if days_to_event <= -1 then eix0 = ix+1; * update when applicability exhausted;
      end;
    end;

    output;
  end;

  keep group date p:;

  stop;
run;
```

Comment: Yes, you can use DATA Step.  At _n_ = 1 load the event group and dates into two arrays and evaluate the flag condition over all events for each trading row.